# Checking if a date is a multiple of 100 days away from another date

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime

I need to check if a date is x*100 days away from another date (True or False). 
I've got something but it's pretty elaborate and I feel it can be simpler:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
def hundredday(date1, date2):
    party = False
    y = 0
    x = date1
    while date1 <= x <= date2:
        x = date1+y*timedelta(days=100)
        if x == date2:
            party = True
        y += 1

    return party
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the number of days between the dates:

```
def hundredday(date1, date2):
    return (date1 - date2).days % 100 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Compute the difference between the 2 days by [subtracting][1]:

Then you can divide by 100 and see if it's an integer. Or, convert to a string, and check the 2 rightmost characters for '00'.